New Ductwork - Attic Sealing
I own a 3 story townhome in a humid coastal town - built in 1973. 2 AC units serve the 2200 square foot house (both 12 years old). 1 serves the bottom two floors the other is the top floor. Started noticing high humidity (with a newly purchased sensor) on the top floor during the fall in the mid 70% to 80% - not good. Also started noticing mold collecting around the outlets or openings in the drywall.
Called in 3 HVAC companies.
1 - charged $125 to replace the filters, flush the drain line and clean the coil. No change.
2 - wants to replace all of the ductwork for $6k - refit registers/returns to ceilings.
3 - wants to pull all of the old insulation and seal the attic, put in new insulation and repair a few places of duct. He said the ducts still look good for $2k
Consensus is that hot humid air is mixing with cold air causing the humidity and mold.
Anyone have any expert thoughts here?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
